# Print large select SQL statement via php

Tags: php, mysql, file-io

I hope this is something you can help me with.
I have through much trial and error come up with this statement which lists everything neatly in my phpmyadmin view.

```
SELECT DISTINCT inzone_product_lang.name, inzone_product.price, (inzone_product.price * 1.25) as pris
FROM inzone_product_lang 
INNER JOIN inzone_product
ON inzone_product.id_product=inzone_product_lang.id_product
ORDER BY inzone_product_lang.name, pris
```

I'd like to make this into a php query and print it - but I am stuck here.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT inzone_product_lang.name, inzone_product.price, (inzone_product.price * 1.25) as pris
FROM inzone_product_lang 
INNER JOIN inzone_product
ON inzone_product.id_product=inzone_product_lang.id_product
ORDER BY inzone_product_lang.name, pris
LIMIT 0, 900
");

$data = mysql_fetch_object($result);
    echo $data->foo();
```

Comment: Why are you stuck? `$data->foo();` I don't see a foo column in your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Does `print_r( $data );` give you any results?

Comment: u need to display query?

Comment: Clearly there is some confusion about whether your question actually means "print the sql statement itself" OR "print the result set which comes from the successful query to the database"

Comment: Yes, this is my first post here - I was too vague with my topic. I would like to query the database for my select statement, and echo the result through php. Basically I would like a neat list to be accessible for myself through a simple link to my php file, rather than having to put my sql statement into phpmyadmin in order to see the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $query="SELECT DISTINCT inzone_product_lang.name, inzone_product.price, inzone_product.price * 1.25) as pris FROM inzone_product_lang INNER JOIN inzone_product ON inzone_product.id_product=inzone_product_lang.id_product ORDER BY inzone_product_lang.name, pris LIMIT 0, 900";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($data = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
    print_r($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the data, like this, if you want it in a table, you can just echo that data in a table row. Something like this:

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo $data->name;
    echo $data->price;
    ...
}
```

Also, you can see the structure of objects like this by using tools like `print_r` (which is especially helpful in logs) and if you have XDebug installed, `var_dump` is very nice to look at.

```
var_dump($data); // Prints to document when loaded
error_log(print_r($data, true)); // Prints to error log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a concatenation string with the new-line characters as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT inzone_product_lang.name, inzone_product.price, (inzone_product.price * 1.25) as pris\n" .
"FROM inzone_product_lang \n" .
"INNER JOIN inzone_product\n" .
"ON inzone_product.id_product=inzone_product_lang.id_product\n" .
"ORDER BY inzone_product_lang.name, pris\n";

mysql_query($query);
```

"\n" is a whitespace. Allways use it in double-quoted strings.
If you want to print the query to a browser, there's a nice PHP function named '[nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)'